# How to get current Location when app is minimized

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a sports application where I have to constantly get accurate live location from user and send it to the server, even when the application is minimized. The official android developer page says background location access is only possible when a user selects 'Allow all the time' on a settings page.

> [*Android Developers > Docs > Guides > Request background location*](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#request-background-location)

This, I find, is programmatically impossible. At the same time, there are multiple apps (Strava , Map runner, runkeeper) which are able to get GPS coordinates when the app is minimized without getting the permission.
If anyone happened to dabble in this sort of thing, I would like to have your inputs. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think those app can get the location on background without specific authorization from the user. Always been asked this from Android 10 onwards, including Google Maps. This is a security measure, there's no way around it except rooting and custom ROMs.

Comment: Those apps probably use a `Foreground Service` which changes things a bit. You are then using a _"foreground location"_ instead.

Comment: Im using Foreground Service  but it isn't working on android 11

Comment: https://kajda.com/2020/09/21/restrictions-to-background-location-and-foreground-services-in-android-11/